# Notification is not closing when multiple application tabs are open

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, push-notification, notifications, windows-10

When the application session times out, I display a dialog to the user saying "The session is about to timeout" and I display 2 buttons on the dialog "Signout" and "StayLoggedIn".

Along with this dialog, I display a desktop Notification to the user which warns the user about the session timing out.

When I click on the 'SignOut' or 'StayLoggedIn' button on the dialog, I need to close the notification too along with the dialog.

I am using Notification.close() to close the notification.

The Notification closes fine when I click on the dialog buttons when I just have one application tab open. 
But if I have 2 application tabs open(eg - google.com,google.com) and click on the dialog buttons in one of the tabs, the notification.close() gets called but it does not close the notification.

Anyone came across similar issue? I am stuck. Need help please. FYI I am on Chrome version 78.

Answer (score 0):

Every tab in chrome is a new process. Windows 10 is process isolated with toast.
The toast created in process A can not access a toast created in process B and vice versa.

Toast notifications usefulness came and gone with the focus assist feature. So honestly I would skip using them in any new app.

Comment: How to get focus to a Chrome tab which created desktop notification? I need to know which window created the notification without clicking on the notification. (I know doing window.focus() will take you to the window the notification was created from if you click on the notification)